# Corrupted resource .cpp file when using QT5_ADD_RESOURCES and multithread compiling with CMake

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, cmake, qt5

The 5.0 release of Qt has brought a set of easier commands to build Qt projects using CMake.
See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/cmake-manual.html. Resources for a project need to be included using the command **QT5_ADD_RESOURCES**.

If my resource file is named for instance Icon32.qrc, the **QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(RESOURCES Icon32.qrc)** command will automatically convert it into a **qrc_Icon32.cpp** file and define a **${RESOURCES}** variable that I will then be able to include into the proper targets.

Doing this works perfectly, *except that I get a compilation error in CDash roughly once every 20 builds*. The error is typically of the following form:

```
/.../CMake/build/qrc_Icon32.cpp:272380:1: error: unknown type name 'qCleanupResources_Icon32'
```

What is happening is that a variable portion of the last line of the **qrc_Icon32.cpp** file is repeated after what should normally the end of file, thus creating one last nonsensical line for the compiler.

Logging what CMake does, it seems that the behavior of **QT5_ADD_RESOURCES** is the following: whenever it reaches a project that requires the resources in question, it executes a *depend* make file that is specific to the compilation target but that still would write the **qrc_Icon32.cpp** *at the root of the build directory*, and this for all targets. So if two targets are being compiled in parallel, two invocations of **rcc** could be writing into the same file at the same time, hence the corruption.

I have not found any report/discussion of this issue/feature on the web so I am wondering if I might have missed something:

Is there a way to tell CMake to save the generated **qrc_Icon32.cpp** in a different location for each target? Better yet, is it possible to tell CMake to call **rcc** only once from its main make file so that **qrc_Icon32.cpp** is later available for all targets?

I guess a workaround would be to create a static library that would be the only one using **${RESOURCES}** and then to link that library into all targets. But still, I think CMake ought to be able to manage its dependencies properly when compiling with the multithreading -j flag.

---

To reproduce the issue, in an empty folder, create a CMakeList.txt containing the following

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.11)
PROJECT(SSCCE CXX)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/Qt-5.3.0 ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(SYSTEM "/usr/local/Qt-5.3.0/include/QtCore")
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(RESOURCES Icon32.qrc)

SET(LIBLIST gobject-2.0 X11-xcb Xi xcb-render-util SM ICE xcb-glx xcb-render xcb-atom xcb-property xcb-event dbus-1 xcb xcb-image xcb-icccm xcb-sync xcb-xfixes xcb-shm xcb-randr xcb-shape xcb-keysyms fontconfig freetype Xrender Xext X11 jpeg png Qt5::Core z m dl gthread-2.0 rt glib-2.0 GL pthread)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(FirstTarget Main1.cpp ${RESOURCES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(FirstTarget ${LIBLIST})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(SecondTarget Main2.cpp ${RESOURCES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(SecondTarget ${LIBLIST})
```

Then Main1.cpp and Main2.cpp are created using

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        std::cout<<"Hello World 1"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The qrc file is

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Icon32/YourImage.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then create a folder named Icon32 and add a png image of your choice name YourImage.png.

Finally, create a build directory, enter it and run:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.8 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-std=c++11 -fPIE' ..
make -j2
```

The output should be something like

```
Scanning dependencies of target FirstTarget_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target SecondTarget_automoc
[ 10%] [ 20%] Automoc for target FirstTarget
Automoc for target SecondTarget
[ 20%] [ 20%] Built target FirstTarget_automoc
Built target SecondTarget_automoc
[ 30%] [ 40%] Generating qrc_Icon32.cpp
Generating qrc_Icon32.cpp
Scanning dependencies of target SecondTarget
Scanning dependencies of target FirstTarget
[ 50%] [ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SecondTarget.dir/Main2.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FirstTarget.dir/Main1.cpp.o
[ 70%] [ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SecondTarget.dir/qrc_Icon32.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FirstTarget.dir/qrc_Icon32.cpp.o
[ 90%] [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SecondTarget.dir /SecondTarget_automoc.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/FirstTarget.dir/FirstTarget_automoc.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable SecondTarget
Linking CXX executable FirstTarget
```

You can see that qrc_Icon32.cpp is created twice at about the same time, at the root of the build directory. The qrc_Icon32.cpp.o files though are properly created in the FirstTarget.dir and SecondTarget.dir so there are no conflicts.

My point is that either:
1) qrc_Icon32.cpp should be created in FirstTarget.dir and SecondTarget.dir as well or
2) it should be created at the root of the build directory, but only once for all targets.

Comment: An actual sscce would not use target_link_libraries, would not set a LIBLIST, would not use AUTOMOC and would not use include_directories as you have done. The c++ file can be more-trivial and the qrc file can include the c++ file instead of requiring the answerer to create an icon file. You also shouldn't need to instruct how to run cmake. The default should be fine. I guess you're using a static Qt, but you should simplify to a shared version for the sscce, because that's what other people use, and it simplifies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

qt5_add_resources writes the file to `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`, not `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`

[https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/d953d9a4c3bdc5ed3b8d380c4b893b51b523bc50:src/corelib/Qt5CoreMacros.cmake#L205](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/d953d9a4c3bdc5ed3b8d380c4b893b51b523bc50%3asrc/corelib/Qt5CoreMacros.cmake#L205)

Ditto Qt 4:

http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob;f=Modules/Qt4Macros.cmake;h=b1b12d68b07aac076719c681fb844f4f98ba8151;hb=HEAD#l212

Update:

With the source code you provided in your update, it is possible to see the issue.

http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-October/024492.html

http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=0ece8f79

http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12311

The workaround is to add a custom target and add explicit depends on that.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(MyTest)

find_package(Qt5Core)

qt5_add_resources(RSCS somefile.qrc)
add_custom_target(gen_qrc DEPENDS ${RSCS})

add_executable(foo foo.cpp ${RSCS})
add_dependencies(foo gen_qrc)
add_executable(bar bar.cpp ${RSCS})
add_dependencies(bar gen_qrc)
```

CMake 3.0 has an AUTORCC feature:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#autorcc

It also puts the generated qrc_ file in the current build dir. CMake 3.1 will put it in a target-specific directory, making this problem go away:

http://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=33774ca2

Answer (score 0):

The reported behavior is due to the fact that **QT5_ADD_RESOURCES** is called early on in the process, during configuration and before compilation actually starts. At this point the variable **${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}** pointed out by steveire is defined as the **root build folder**. (This can be easily tested by adding a **MESSAGE(** output in **Qt5CoreMacros.cmake**.

The outcome of the function **QT5_ADD_RESOURCES** is to create custom commands that will be called during the compilation process:
https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/d953d9a4c3bdc5ed3b8d380c4b893b51b523bc50%3asrc/corelib/Qt5CoreMacros.cmake#L231

If multiple targets are defined then those custom commands could later be called in parallel at the same time. At that moment, the **${outfile}** will not be redefined using the then current **${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}** and thus parallel processes will write in the same file at the root of the build directory.

Looking at the code for **QT5_ADD_RESOURCES** no mechanism/option seems to be available to correct that behavior in case of multithreaded compilation, however, as pointed out by steveire, the workaround for the underlying custom command function can also be succesfully applied.

Comment: Why do you emphasise that the file is created in the root build folder? Do you have targets in multiple folders? I just tried that and it works - the qrc_.*.cpp files are created in each subdir. Create a sscce.

Comment: Given the depedencies, creating a sscce is tough, but here's my best shot at it. Depending on your Linux distro, you'll have to edit the LIBLIST variable. Let me know if you have any problem running it. Cheers,